# Perl - Call PHP file from Perl

Tags: php, perl, cgi

**phptest.php**

```
<?php
echo "<h2>PHP is Fun!</h2>";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
echo "I'm about to learn PHP!<br>";
echo "This ", "string ", "was ", "made ", "with multiple parameters.";
?>
```

**perltest.cgi**

```
#!C:\\Perl\\bin\\perl.exe
use DBI;
use Archive::Zip;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
use CGI;

require "header.cgi";

my $query = new CGI;
print $query->header ( );
exec('C:\php phptest.php');
```

I'm trying to execute php file from perl. What I get is a just blank page without any error message. Both files are located in the same folder. When i try to run the php file in browser I get as per below screen shot.
[image]
and from CMD.
[image]
Please advice where I did wrong.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use `use warnings` and `use strict` in your perl script and then run your perl script from command prompt to check it is working fine or not.

Use the backtick operator:

```
my $php = `/path/to/yourscript.php`;
```

Comment: Edited : exec('C:/php D:/PPC/phptest.php');.. still same

Comment: @chinna_82 : see my edited answer. And remember there is a difference between exec and backtick.